# When generating SubSonic DAL, is it possible to have .gen.cs in the generated filenames?

Tags: subsonic

When generating my DAL files with SubSonic, I'd like the names of the files to be .gen.cs.  The main reason for this is that the files are partial classes, and I would like to add some additional implementation details into another source file for the table called .cs.  This is somewhat the standard pattern for generated source files  , and I'm wondering if its possible with SubSonic?  I'm using SubSonic 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you might be able to do this by using a set of custom templates, but the CS_ClassTemplate.aspx (or VB_ClassTemplate.aspx) doesn't control the file name of the class.

I don't think this is possible.

As an alternative, you can do what I do. I have a "generated" directory, such as \database\generated and then I put my partial classes at \database\custom. As long as the namespaces of the files in the two different directories match (like .database or whatever), then it works fine. By using two different directories, it's easier to find your custom files without looking at the generated ones.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is what I expected, but wanted confirmation from someone more knowledgeable...